# Power supplies separation in PCB for an Arduino-like Shield

Tags: pcb-design, dac

I could not find a cut-dry answer anywhere on this issue and I'm struggling a bit on the design of a PCB.
Note, this is the first time I design a PCB, and this issue is actually not so relevant, but still, for the sake of learning I'll post the question anyway.

The shield consists of a DAC driving various transconductors.
The DAC is a multi-channel [nanoDAC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5674-5674R-5679-5679R.pdf) from Texas Instrument.

I'm planning to build a 4-layer PCB.
The ground plane will be split between the DAC and the transconductors (but still connected on a point).
The power supply plane will be also split in two. However, I will have to deal with 3 different supply voltages and I'd prefer to not split the plane even more:

1. The (up to) +30 V for the transconductors
2. The DAC power supply (from 2.7 V to 5.5 V)
3. The logic voltage level (from 1.6 to 5.5 V)

For the sake of flexibility, I'd like to have the option to power the DAC with the 3.3 and 5 V supplied by the Arduino, but also an external power supply. I'll do that using jumpers.
I'd like to have the same flexibility for the logic level and use the IOREF pin of the Arduino or another external reference. Is it ok to just connect the logic level with a wire track, even on the opposite side of the board? Is it bad practice? I'll connect the logical inputs to this same voltage...

Comment: Hmm, a DAC with 8 uS settling time, and it's really likely spec'd for 1 kHz.  Do whatever you want to the planes, it's likely not to matter, unless you provide us with some more/tighter circuit performance requirements.  You could forget the planes, and route with traces (as long as you do everything else right), and you would probably be fine.  BTW, that DAC is an expensive beast.

Comment: Thanks! I think that covers it